# check folder exist and create folder in .pro file

Tags: qt, qmake

I have to create a folder in my target path and copy the header files.

so i used the following command in .pro file

```
 DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK = $${CORE_API_PATH}/Include/spgc/
    DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK ~= s,/,\\,g
    QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(mkdir $${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK} $$escape_expand(\n\t))
    for(FILE,EXPORTED_HEADERS_WIN){
                QMAKE_POST_LINK +=$$quote(cmd /c copy /y $${FILE} $${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK}&$$escape_expand(\n\t))
    }
```

it is creating the folder in first time. but on building second i have to avoid creation of spgc folder (as already exist) .

also qt build  throws error if spgc folder already exist.

i tried

```
!exists($${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK})
    {
        $$quote($${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK})
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(mkdir $${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK} $$escape_expand(\n\t))
    }
```

but even if the folder present , !exists() function been called and creating the folder.

Comment: What if you write `QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(if not exists $${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK} mkdir $${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK})`

Comment: ok i will check and update . thanks vahancho

Comment: @vahancho : it is not entering inside the function , even the folder is not present .

Comment: I'm not sure about `qmake` syntax, but the idea is using the following batch command `if not exists my_dir mkdir my_dir`. So that `my_dir` will be created only if it doesn't exist.

Comment: any how it helped me a lot vahancho . i will find some alternate way if i can and post here . thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is how i resolved it

```
exists($$DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK) {
        message("existing")
    } else {
            QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(mkdir $${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK} $$escape_expand(\n\t))
    }
```

i added if with empty and in else created the directory

Answer (score 3):

I know that is a quite old question, but I had the same problem and I think that I have now figured out the solution.
In your code the problem is the bracket: it should stay on the same line of the condition.

This should work:

```
!exists($${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK}) {   
    $$quote($${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK})
    QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(mkdir $${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK} $$escape_expand(\n\t))
}
```

It sounds ridiculous but that's it...

Comment: This is the correct answer by far. The only problem in the OP's post was the `{` in his code block needed to be on the same line as the `!exists(xxxx)` statement.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out for posterity that `QMAKE_MKDIR_CMD` automatically expands to checking whether the folder exists first.
https://forum.qt.io/topic/47895/qmake_mkdir_cmd-how-to/3

Answer (score 1):

for prebuild
`mkdir.commands = $(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) $${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK} $(MKDIR) $${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK}
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mkdir`

for postbuild
 `QMAKE_POST_LINK += $(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) $${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK} $(MKDIR) $${DESTDIR_WIN_CELLTWEAK}`

add lines to .pro file